# J Oliver EventStore - Saga Examples

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

I was wondering if there is any documentation/guidance on using Saga's and the EventStore. Part of my confusion is that when you look at using a Service Bus like NServiceBus or MassTransit the too have the concept of a Saga. I know the EventStore itself does not have the Saga in the code but the CommonDomain project does and they work together. Do I use the Saga infrastructure in the CommonDomain/EventStore or rely on ServiceBus Saga support? Or could both be used together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet for a saga example is on my blog: [Part I](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-sagas-with-event-sourcing-part-i-of-ii/) and [Part II](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-sagas-with-event-sourcing-part-ii-of-ii/)

You're more than welcome to use MassTransit or NServiceBus for sagas.  I have a simple implementation using CommonDomain because I was trying to avoid a dependency on those frameworks and because I wanted to leverage event sourcing to facilitate sagas.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, your blog raised some further questions however - would the dispatch of Commands not be lost in the event of a system crash as they are being sent seperately from the write transation? I am trying to have the EventStore send commands for me after commit of the saga by combining the Event and Commands in to one stream but not sure of this is a good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429626/eventsourced-saga-implementation